# ElasticSearch with Hadoop data duplication issue

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

I have a requirement as follows :

**Whatever data is there in hadoop, i need to make it searchable (and vice-versa).**

So, for this , I use `ElasticSearch` where we can use `elasticsearch-hadoop plug-in` to send a data from hadoop to Elastic.And a real-time search is now possible.

But, my question is, **isn't there a duplication of data**. Whatever the data is in hadoop , same is duplicated in Elastic search with 
indexing. Is there any way of get rid of this duplication OR my concept is wrong. I search a lot but don't find any clue about this duplication issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you specify an immutable ID for each rows in elasticsearch (eg : a customerID for example), all inserts of existing datas will be only updates.

Extract from official documentation about insertion method (cf http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_operation):

> index (default) :new data is added while existing data (based on its
>   id) is replaced (reindexed).

If you have "customer" dataset in pig, just store datas like that :

```
A = LOAD '/user/hadoop/customers.csv' USING PigStorage()
                    ....;

B = FOREACH A GENERATE customerid, ...;


STORE B INTO 'foo/customer' USING org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage('es.nodes = localhost','es.http.timeout = 5m','es.index.auto.create = true','es.input.json = true','es.mapping.id =customerid','es.batch.write.retry.wait = 30', 'es.batch.size.entries = 500');
--,'es.mapping.parent = customer');
```

To perform a new search on Hadoop just use the custom loader :

```
A = LOAD 'foo/customer' USING org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage('es.query=?me*');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply rnio.In case of repeated firing the same query, you are right. But, just see the data movement in the first fire. While running for the first time also, all data are transfertd to Elastic right. My question targeted towared that duplicated data.

Comment: I not sure to understand. If you have duplicates in your dataset you can remove them through a Pig aggregation or with a nested foreach.